# Linux multi-server user access

Tags: users, authentication

Our organization has a private network of Linux servers. This network is air gapped from the internet and we have limited personal access to the network and servers.

Each server has a standard user login and a root user login. Our shop assigns universal login ids and passwords. For example:

- standard user login = `foo`, password = `bar`
- root user login = `super`, password = `user`

All our procedures say to log in as `foo` or `super` using the relevant password.

For traceability reasons we would like to modify that so that each authorized user has a unique standard user login but continue using the default password. The root level access login is not expected to change.

For example, if I was user `foo93` I could log into any of our servers using `foo93` and `bar`. Someone else could log in as `foo29`.

I envision something like this:

- log into `serverX` as `foo93`
- `serverX` checks with some central server to see if `foo93` is a valid user
- central server replies yes or no
- if yes, standard level access is granted to `serverX`.

Is this doable? How? If somebody points me at where to look, I can run with that.

I can do basic stuff in the CLI, but I don't know where to start looking for an answer for this. I did some google search for access or password control. I got interesting results that IMO didn't apply to the question.

Comment: If you keep the same password for all users, this is at best an honour system. You might as well tell them to write their name into some file instead. It won't help with traceability in the event of an actual malicious activity by a disgruntled employee.

Comment: @muru Even worse, can any user log in over the network as super/user? Absolutely no traceability if an employee decided to bork the company's servers.

Comment: Let me say that this is very unusual for air-gapped networks, and as you note, in the spirit of traceability, should not have been set up. I believe it defies US government norms for confidential computing in natsec sensitive areas, as far as I've been told. So, you're doing very well getting rid of this! Also, if you have even the slightest hunch that someone might have had (or still try before you roll out the new system) an intent to abuse the root access they have to install a rootkit and hide any trace *they* did it, and still be able to anonymously login as root, flatten all machines,

Comment: and set them up freshly. A machine where someone else has been root isn't to be trusted anymore (unless you have hardware-based software integrity attestation, which doesn't seem to be the case here).

Comment: Never mind. I misunderstood the requirements. Users can have individual passwords, but nothing stops them from using the same password. For example, bar.

Answer (score 1):

> The root level access login is not expected to change.

This is definitely not an option. Why would someone who's making mistake (or is doing mischievous things) such that you want to track what happened have logged in as their individual user? They won't. Exactly the things that are important to track will be done as root. Having anonymous root is not responsible.

I frankly would disable root access to *everyone*. There's no privileged user that you can directly login as (or the root password is long, and on a drive in their office that only the admin knows the decryption key to). If things need to be done as root, use `sudo` and log accesses centrally. That's a fairly standard policy!

> log into serverX as foo93 serverX checks with some central server to see if foo93 is a valid user central server replies yes or no if yes, standard level access is granted to serverX. I

This sounds like a standard scheme: PAM with a centralized *identity management*. That exists - in the Windows world, it's called "Active Directory" (and you can actually authenticate against an Active Directory Domain controller). For a Linux environment, with a smaller setup where you don't need single sign on for more than Linux logins: you configure the clients to use SSSD for logins, specifically, through the `ldap` plugin. That asks a central server for authentication. It can also do things like create directories the first time someone logs in on a machine.

You'll find guides for your specific linux distro of choice (you sadly haven't specified), if you search for something like `distroname SSSD LDAP guide`. So here's the rough idea:

0. pick a name for your internal domain; "airgappednet" or something.
1. Dedicate one computer as central identity server (typically, you do go with a VM for this – simply because you want to be able to take a snapshot and migrate that to a backup computer; otherwise you're building a single point of failure. Also, you're air-gapped, and it's easier to set up a VM when you have internet, then copy the VM image onto a drive, carry that over the air gap, and then set up the confidential stuff)

   1. install openldap on that.
   2. Set up Slapd (for which you'll need self-signed SSL certificates) on that server VM, so that you get encrypted communication with the authentication servr (never do things unencrypted when they involve passwords, not even in the same airgapped network)
   3. add users to the LDAP database; the domain will be part of the `dc` prefix.
2. Configure the clients to use LDAP to authenticate users

   1. install sssd, sssd-ldap and ldap clients
   2. use authselect to select sssd as authorization provider software
   3. configure /etc/openldap/ldap.conf to use your LDAP server
   4. configure /etc/sssd/sssd.conf to use your LDAP server and the right prefix